# Expected behavior of `for` loop in rust

Tags: rust

I'm new to rust and I've question about the way the for loop.

```
fn main() {
    for x in 1 .. 10 {
        println!("x == {}", x);
    }
}
```

The output of the program is

```
x == 1
x == 2
x == 3
x == 4
x == 5
x == 6
x == 7
x == 8
x == 9
```

I was expecting for loop to execute and display `x == 10` but it stopped at 9.
Is this expected behavior

Comment: the upper bound is exclusive, so it will not be in the output.  Check the docs: https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.2.0/book/for-loops.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected! The `0 .. 10` is an "exclusive range" meaning it does **not** include the upper bound. There is also an "inclusive range" syntax in the works which **does** include the upper bound, but it has not been released yet. The new syntax is being tracked in [rust-lang/rust#28237](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/28237).

For now you can make the loop include 10 by writing an exclusive range with 11 as the upper bound.

```
fn main() {
    for x in 1..11 {
        println!("x == {}", x);
    }
}
```

Or by starting at 0 and printing `x + 1`.

```
fn main() {
    for x in 0..10 {
        println!("x == {}", x + 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `x..y` syntax in Rust indicates a Range.

Ranges in Rust, like many other languages and libraries, have an *exclusive upper-bound*:

https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/for.html

> One of the easiest ways to create an iterator is to use the range notation `a..b`. This yields values from `a` (inclusive) to `b` (exclusive) in steps of one.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is expected. The end is not inclusive with when creating a range using `..`.

In patterns you can use `...` for an inclusive range and there is an unstable feature that allows you to use `..=` to create an inclusive range.